# c# copy settings from old version which has diff namespace

Tags: c#

in order to make settings shared between multiple projects I moved the file to a base project. But then the namespace of the settings file changed with it.

I.E. it used to be `OldNameSpace.Properties.Settings` and now its `NewNameSpace.Properties.Settings`

I am having trouble copying the old settings into the new with `.Upgrade()` since the name spaces are different.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the namespace override in the file properties of the settings file. This will allow you to keep the old namespace and avoid the problem you mentioned.

In the project use `F4` to bring up the Properties pane and then navigate to the Settings file in the solution explorer, it should be there in that properties window that you can edit it. The property name is `Custom Tool Namespace`, that is where you define the namespace you wish to use.